# Python: Is there a way to import non-standard modules without installing through pip?

Tags: python, module

Is there a way to import non-standard modules without installing through pip?

I want to share some Python code with some friends but it relies on a locally installed module. Is there a way my friends can run my code without having to install the module locally?

ex. gmplot

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmplot/1.1.0

Comment: Short answer: Nope.  There are other ways to install the module, but if it is required for the program to run, ... it is required for the program to run.

Comment: Maybe look into cxfreeze to convert to .exe, this will compile your modules that you import. At least the standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a quick setup.py that specifies dependencies. And yeah... use pip to install it.

https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html

http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/

Although I disagree with the other answers here. It is actually possible without pip, you could just take the sources of the module you need and ship it alongside your code. I certainly don't recommend that tho.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Install them through some other method.

Seriously, though, if the code is importing modules then those modules have to be on the machine running the code.

If this is just a module or two you could copy it over by hand (using `scp` or whatever) and put it in the appropriate location, but you have to get it over there.